# How to Convert deep nested Objects literal to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build a treeselect component using an [ant design UI framework](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/), The requirement of this component is to supply the treeData in particular format (Array of Objects), However in my application i am getting the data as an object literal as shown below.

```
output = {"Node3":{
    "Node": "Node3",
    "children": {
        "Node3A" : {
            "Node": "Node3A",
            "children": {
                "Node3A1": {
                    "Node": "Node3A1",
                    "children": {
                        "Node3A1": {
                            "Node": "Node3A1x"
                        },
                        "Node3A1":{
                            "Node": "Node3A1y"
                        },
                        "Node3A1": {
                            "Node": "Node3A1z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Node3A2":{
                    "Node": "Node3A2"
                },
                "Node3A3":{
                    "Node": "Node3A3"
                }
            }
        }
    }}}
```

I would like to convert it to output like below, so that i can supply this data as a treeData to get the desired output within the tree-select component.

```
{
    "Node": "Node3",
    "children": [
        {
            "Node": "Node3A",
            "children": [
                {
                    "Node": "Node3A1",
                    "children":
                        [
                            {
                                "Node": "Node3A1x"
                            },
                            {
                                "Node": "Node3A1y"
                            },
                            {
                                "Node": "Node3A1z"
                            }
                        ]
                },
                {
                    "Node": "Node3A2"
                },
                {
                    "Node": "Node3A3"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Basically, I would like to get the output in such a way that the children properties of object literals are converted to array of objects. Looking for the solution in Javascript (ES6 preferably)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately your "question" (which doesn't actually appear to be a question, just a statement of fact) is well below the standard required.  Please read the [ask] page and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = {
  "Node3": {
    "Node": "Node3",
    "children": {
      "Node3A": {
        "Node": "Node3A",
        "children": {
          "Node3A1": {
            "Node": "Node3A1",
            "children": {
              "Node3A1x": {
                "Node": "Node3A1x"
              },
              "Node3A1y": {
                "Node": "Node3A1y"
              },
              "Node3A1z": {
                "Node": "Node3A1z"
              }
            }
          },
          "Node3A2": {
            "Node": "Node3A2"
          },
          "Node3A3": {
            "Node": "Node3A3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function transform(obj) {
  if (obj.children) {
    obj.children = Object.values(obj.children).map(transform);
  }
  return obj;
}

const result = transform(Object.values(input).pop());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you @ponury-kostek, This is the exact solution i was looking for.